# How to divide by 13 without "/" operation

Tags: c, math, division

Is there any way to divide by 13 without actual division operation?

I have found only tests that checks divisibility by 13.

I am looking for something similar to this division by 10:

```
static A_UINT32 div_10(A_UINT32 duration)
{
    A_UINT64 invDivisor = 0x1999999A;
    return (A_UINT32)((invDivisor * duration) >> 32);
}
```

or to this division by 3:

```
static A_UINT32 div_3(A_UINT32 duration)
{
    duration += (duration + 0x2) >> 2;
    duration += (duration + 0x8) >> 4;
    duration += (duration + 0x80) >> 8;
    duration += (duration + 0x8000) >> 16;
    return duration >>= 2;
}
```

Comment: @gsamaras, I hoped to find something similar to this 

`static A_UINT32 div_10(A_UINT32 duration)
{
    A_UINT64 invDivisor = 0x1999999A;
    return (A_UINT32)((invDivisor * duration) >> 32);
}`

Comment: You could just do `x / 13` and let the compiler optimise it. That doesn't eliminate the division operator, but the compiler may avoid using 'divide' instructions to evaluate it.

Comment: Think about what your `div_10` does. It computes `m * duration / (2^32)`. In other words, they came up with a value `m` (in this case, specifically `0x1999999A`) such that `(m * duration) / (2^32)` is as close as possible to `duration / 10`. In other words, they have found values `p` and `m` such that `2^p` is as close to `10 * m` as possible. You want to find `p` and `m` such that `2^p` is as close to `13 * m` as possible.

Comment: This answer is courtesy of the GCC compiler: `static A_UINT32 div_13(A_UINT32 duration)
{
 A_UINT64 intDivisor = 1321528399;
 return (A_UINT32)((intDivisor * duration) >> 34);
}
`

Comment: @lurker Well a useful tip is to get GCC to do the work, look at the assembly output and write a function to do the same thing. :)

Comment: @lurker, thank you. I got it.
@IanAbbott, thank you, but value `0x13B13B14` with right 32 bits shift more convenient for me.

Comment: IMO, division by a specific constant (13) can yield more ad-hoc answers than the general case. Not a duplicate.

Comment: What is the range of the dividend ?

Comment: if you want to manually calculate the magic number without the compiler then [hackers delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm) comes to the help

Comment: @Dropper note: the approximation with 32 bits shift only works up to 2^30. For `duration=1073741837` (`=2^30+13`) you get 82595526 instead of 82595525.

Comment: also the approximation for dividing by 10 with only 32 bits shift only works up to 2^30. The only correct solution for all 32 bit unsigned integers with 64 bit intermediate result is `duration*3435973837/2^35`

Comment: And if any of the above issues matter at all, use the built-in divide and let the compiler handle it.  If this is a for fun thing, then have fun.  You could also revert back to the old school shifts and subtracts that was done for generic divides in systems that didn't have them.

Comment: @coproc maximal duration value is 6386640 or something around that. It is less than 2^30. I think I am okay with such accuracy.

Comment: you mentioned `tests that checks divisibility by 13`, so actually do you want a division by 13 or a modulo 13? The answers will be completely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for two positive integers k and m, s.t.

```
[n*k/2^m] = [n/13],  0 <= n < 2^32
```

where `[x]` means "rounding down" the rational number `x` and `n` runs through all 32-bit unsigned integers. These 2^32 equations can be reduced to two inequalities:

```
k > 2^m/13
k < 2^m*N/(13N-1)
```

where `N = [2^32/13]`. So we have to look for a value of `m` s.t. there is an integer value between `2^m/13` and `2^m*N/(13N-1)`. Since we carry out the computations with 64 bit we have to make sure that `n*k` is representable by 64 bits for all interesting n, hence we need `(2^32-1)*k < 2^64`, i.e. `k < 2^32`. From the first inequality we get `2^m/13 < 2^32-1` which means `m <= 35`. Now computing the lower and upper boundaries for `k` for `m` up to 35 we get the following table:

```
 m      2^m/13      2^m*N/(13N-1)
        ....
31   165191049.85    165191049.88
32   330382099.69    330382099.77
33   660764199.38    660764199.54
34  1321528398.77   1321528399.08
35  2643056797.54   2643056798.15
```

When `m < 34` there is no integer value in the range for k. But for `m=34` and `m=35` there is exactly one integer in the range. Hence the possible solutions: `k = 1321528399, m = 34` or `k = 2643056798, m = 35`.

Here are solutions for other divisors:

```
 d   m      k
 3  33  2863311531
 5  34  3435973837
 6  34  2863311531
 9  35  3817748708
10  35  3435973837
11  35  3123612579
12  35  2863311531
13  35  2643056798
15  35  2290649225
17  36  4042322161
```

There do not seem to be solutions of this form for division by 7, 14, 19, 21 (and more) if one wants correct results for all 32 bit unsigned integers with 64 bit calculations.